# Chrome new update breaks A5 print layout

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4, printing

I have a simple single html page that I need to print in A5 paper layout every now and then... In the **latest chrome update**, when trying to print in A5 the layout breaks (first image shows the correct layout, second image shows the broken layout when choosing the A5 printing option)... Below is my code (using `bootstrap v4.6.0`) and some images for clarification

```
<html>
<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
  
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

  <style>

    body  {
          font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Verdana';
          font-size: 26px;

          margin: 10mm;
        }

    hr {
      border-color: #4C4E4D;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #4C4E4D;
    }

    .box {
      box-shadow: 0 3px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.50);
    }
    
    .arabic {
      font-family: 'Scheherazade New';
    }

    .title {
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    #footer {
      
      border-top: 1px solid #4C4E4D;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  

    <div class='row mb-5'>
      <div class='col-sm-2 text-right'>
        <img src="gold_logo2.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-10 text-center'>
        <p style="color: #B99534; font-family: 'mohammad bold art 1'; font-size: 40px;">
          الدكتور هادي عبدالوهاب الطباطبائي
        
        <br>
          <span style="color: #000; font-family: 'mohammad bold art 1'; font-size: 26px;">
          بورد (دكتوراه) جراحة العظام والكسور والمفاصل 
          </span>
        <br>
          <span style="color: #000; font-family: 'mohammad bold art 1'; font-size: 26px;">
          عضو الجمعية السويسرية لجراحة العظام والكسور
          </span>
        <br>
          <span style="color: #000; font-family: 'mohammad bold art 1'; font-size: 26px;">
          زمالة جراحة وناظور الكف والأطراف العليا (الهند)
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

 

  <footer id="footer">
      <div class="container text-center mt-2">
        
          <span style="color: #000; font-family: 'mohammad bold art 1'; font-size: 26px;">
            شارع الإسكان - مقابل حي عدن - قرب صيدلية العراب
          </span>
          <br>
          07839146748
          <br>
          <p class="text-muted text-right" style="font-size: 14px;"><u>Reg. No. 43044</u><p>
          <!-- <p class="text-muted text-right" style="font-size: 7px;">{{id}}</p> -->
        
        
      </div>
  </footer> 

</body>

</html>
```

[image: This is the expected print layout, which is correct when choosing A4 printing option]
[image: This is the broken layout, happens when choosing the A5 printing option. It was working correctly before the latest chrome update]